# Attempting to access Bitbucket API endpoint with 'x-token-auth' doesn't work

Tags: git, curl, bitbucket

We want to create a link to download a file from a private Bitbucket repo.

We created an access token with 'read' access to the `repository` scope. This Curl command works fine:

```bash
URLHOST="https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories"
URLPATH="/$WORKSPACE/$REPO/src/$COMMIT/$FILEPATH"
URL="$URLHOST$URLPATH"
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" $URL
```

However, we want to be able to use the link without custom headers, i.e. a URL that we could paste into a web browser's address bar to download the file.

I've tried various combinations of `x-token-auth` and `?access_token` without success:

```bash
URLHOST="https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories"
URLHOST="https://x-token-auth:$TOKEN@api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories"

URLHOST="https://bitbucket.org"
URLHOST="https://x-token-auth:$TOKEN@bitbucket.org"

URLPATH="/$WORKSPACE/$REPO/src/$COMMIT/$FILEPATH"
URLPATH="/$WORKSPACE/$REPO/raw/$COMMIT/$FILEPATH"

URLSEARCH=""
URLSEARCH="?access_token=$TOKEN"

URL="$URLHOST$URLPATH$URLSEARCH"

curl $URL -vvvv
```

The response either includes:

```
Authentication problem. Ignoring this.
```

...or:

```json
{"type":"error","error":{"message":"You may not have access to this repository or it no 
longer exists in this workspace. If you think this repository exists and you have access, make sure you are authenticated."}
```

Is this possible with Bitbucket access tokens?